# Connecting an arduino, accelerometer and a camera

Tags: matlab, camera, arduino, accelerometer

I am look at using accelerometer(s) as a wearable sensor to track the acceleration of someone's leg while they perform various motions. I would like to video/ take photos of the subject whilst the accelerometer(s) are collecting data. Is there someway to sync the camera with the data from the accelerometer? In order to draw the acceleration vectors on a frames/image from the camera. Therefore, the camera an accelerometer would have to be synchronised to be in real time. Could I use MATLAB?

Comment: Assuming you're successful, where will you store all these data on the Arduino?  You know it has almost no RAM, right?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure there's a way to do that using MATLAB. But this is way too broad. Please read through [ask]; we do best with specific code-related questions and problems. Your biggest issue right now is prototyping and figuring out how to get both sets of data to the same place in real-time, we can't build that system for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have actually done something similar in the past and it might give you a starting point.

I synchronized the video from a webcam and accelerometer data from an IMU connected to an arduino. I ended up programming most if it in Java but that's not really necessary you could probably do it in Matlab.

Assuming that you have already programmed the arduino to sample the accelerometer, you can send that data to a PC via a serial connection. Then you would connect the camera to the same PC, and use Matlab to start recording from both of them simultaneously.

It's far to complicated for me to explain all of the details in this post but I hope this gives you an idea of how to begin.

Goodluck!